# Check if a single character is changed to a string or if it was more than one character

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good day.

I need to check if a string was changed one or more than one character. eg:

```
var string = "Orange"; //default
var string2 = "Orange"; // Equals
var string3 = "Oronge"; // orOnge just 1
var string4 = "Orongo"; // orOngO 2 or more.

verificar(string, string2); // return 2
verificar(string, string3); // return 0
verificar(string, string4); // return 1

function verificar(a, b){
 //Here I need the code which returns 0 if only one character is modified or 1 if it has been modified two or more characters, or 2 in case you have not changed anything.
}
```

Any suggestions?

Greetings!

Comment: Will cadenaModificada always be the same length as cadena?

Comment: No, they are different strings

Comment: but can they be different lengths, like "orange" and "orangeeeeee"?

Comment: Yes. Can be Orange and Orangeeeeeee. Its a problem :/

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is the [Levenshtein Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

> In information theory and computer science, the Levenshtein distance is a string metric for measuring the difference between two sequences. Informally, the Levenshtein distance between two words is the minimum number of single-character edits (i.e. insertions, deletions or substitutions) required to change one word into the other.

There are a number of implementations easily found with a Google search, such as [this one](https://gist.github.com/andrei-m/982927).

Answer (score 0):

This should get the job done if a and b are the same length. Loop through a, check if each character is changed and if so, add to count.

```
function verificar(a, b){
    count = 0
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i ++) {
        if (a[i] != b[i]) { 
            count++
        }
    }
    if (count == 0) {
        return "Equal"
    }
    else if (count == 1) {
         return "1 change"
    }
    else {
        return "More than 1 change"
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gtqr3hx1/6/

Comment: @Jesús Alberto Carrillo García Well then this is a bit trickier, I'm not sure I can help, sorry! I'd look at some examples in the link that Draco18s posted: https://gist.github.com/andrei-m/982927

Comment: Yes!  Draco18s has the solution. c: Thank u anywhere